# Use of a cordless drill

Tags: powertools

I recently bought a Makita cordless drill w/no battery i have a battery for this model but it says it uses a NiCd battery which mine isnt. can i still use this battery?

Thanks

Comment: yes well you need to check the voltage of the battery. you can run a cordless drill off a dc power supply from your wall. the drill works on a min voltage so if you have a battery thats above the min but is not the max voltage you should be fine. it may or may not last as long you have to check the specs of the battery. some battery have 2 volts and some have 30 volts. you wont blow up the drill because you put the wrong battery in it. it just wont wrok. its all dc power

Answer (score 2):

Before 2000 many cordless tools had **nickel-cadmium** battery packs.   Some time in the early 00's, tool makers started making **nickel metal hydride** battery packs.  As is often the case with batteries, the chemistry involved gave them the same operating voltage (1.2 volts per cell) as nickel-cadmium.  And internally, the cells are compatible in size and shape, so it was an easy swaperoo.

An older tool made for NiCd will work fine with a NiMH battery pack, even though it's not labeled for NiMH.  That's simply because it was made before NiMH came along.

A NiMH battery pack will work anywhere a NiCd does, and give ~50% extra runtime.

A battery charger made for NiCd may not charge NiMH correctly, the biggest danger is overcharge, because NiCd is fairly sanguine about overcharge, but it damages NiMH.

Answer (score 0):

yes well you need to check the voltage of the battery. you can run a cordless drill off a dc power supply from your wall. the drill works on a min voltage so if you have a battery thats above the min but is not the max voltage you should be fine. it may or may not last as long you have to check the specs of the battery. some battery have 2 volts and some have 30 volts. you wont blow up the drill because you put the wrong battery in it. it just wont wrok. its all dc powe